# Unable to get location after reboot the phone and internet stays off Android , Service Location

Tags: java, android, location, android-service

`I'm facing an issue with my Android app where the map fails to load and I'm unable to obtain the user's location after rebooting the device when there is no internet connection. I have ensured that the GPS is turned on and have requested location updates. However, the map remains blank and the location data is not available.

My service is getting started I logged it only location data is not available

Is there a way to handle this situation gracefully and ensure that the map loads and location updates work even if there is no internet connection after a device reboot? Are there any specific considerations or code snippets that I should implement to tackle this issue effectively? Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "channel_01";
    public static final String ACTION_BROADCAST = PACKAGE_NAME + ".broadcast";
    public static final String EXTRA_LOCATION = PACKAGE_NAME + ".location";
    public static final String EXTRA_TIME = PACKAGE_NAME + ".time";
    public static final String EVENT = "event";
    private static final String EXTRA_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION = PACKAGE_NAME +".started_from_notification";
    private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 5000;
    private static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345678;
    private boolean mChangingConfiguration = false;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
    private Handler mServiceHandler;
    private Location mLocation;

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private static final String TAG = "ttttttttttttttttttt";
    String trip_id;
    Timer timer;
    int count = 0;
    double distance;
    List<Location> data = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationRes
 
ult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
                onNewLocation(locationResult.getLastLocation());
            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationAvailability(@NonNull LocationAvailability locationAvailability) {

                super.onLocationAvailability(locationAvailability);
                Log.d(TAG, "onLocationAvailability: "+locationAvailability.isLocationAvailable());
                enableLocation(locationAvailability.isLocationAvailable());
            }
        };
        createLocationRequest();
        getLastLocation();
        HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread(TAG);
        handlerThread.start();
        mServiceHandler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        // Android O requires a Notification Channel.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = getString(R.string.app_name);
            // Create the channel for the notification
            NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            // Set the Notification Channel for the Notification Manager.
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
        }
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service started");

        try {
            boolean startedFromNotification = intent.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION, false);

            // We got here because the user decided to remove location updates from the notification.
            if (startedFromNotification) {
                removeLocationUpdates();
                stopSelf();
            }
        } catch (Exception ignored) {

        }
        // Tells the system to not try to recreate the service after it has been killed.
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mChangingConfiguration = true;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Called when a client (MainActivity in case of this sample) comes to the foreground
        // and binds with this service. The service should cease to be a foreground service
        // when that happens.
        Log.i(TAG, "in onBind()");
        stopForeground(true);
        mChangingConfiguration = false;
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
        // Called when a client (MainActivity in case of this sample) returns to the foreground
        // and binds once again with this service. The service should cease to be a foreground
        // service when that happens.
        Log.i(TAG, "in onRebind()");
        stopForeground(true);
        mChangingConfiguration = false;
        super.onRebind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Last client unbound from service");

        // Called when the last client (MainActivity in case of this sample) unbinds from this
        // service. If this method is called due to a configuration change in MainActivity, we
        // do nothing. Otherwise, we make this service a foreground service.
        if (!mChangingConfiguration && ExtraUtils.requestingLocationUpdates(this)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Starting foreground service");
            /*
            // TODO(developer). If targeting O, use the following code.
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                mNotificationManager.startServiceInForeground(new Intent(this,
                        LocationUpdatesService.class), NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
            } else {
                startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
            }
             */
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
        }
        return true; // Ensures onRebind() is called when a client re-binds.
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mServiceHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        new DbHelper(this).updateTripEnd();
    }

    public void removeLocationUpdates() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Removing location updates");
        try {
            mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
            stopTimer();
            ExtraUtils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, false);
            new SharedDB(this).setLocationRequest(false);
            stopSelf();
        } catch (SecurityException unlikely) {

            new SharedDB(this).setLocationRequest(true);
            ExtraUtils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, true);
            Log.e(TAG, "Lost location permission. Could not remove updates. " + unlikely);

        }
    }

    public void requestLocationUpdates(String trip_id) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Requesting location updates");
        this.trip_id = trip_id;
        timer = new Timer();
        ExtraUtils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, true);
        new SharedDB(this).setLocationRequest(true);

        startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LocationUpdatesService.class));
        try {
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
            startTimer();
        } catch (SecurityException unlikely) {
            ExtraUtils.setRequestingLocationUpdates(this, false);
            new SharedDB(this).setLocationRequest(false);
            Log.e("updateTimer", "Lost location permission. Could not request updates. " + unlikely);
        }
    }

    private void getLastLocation() {
        try {
            mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                        mLocation = task.getResult();
                    } else {
                        // TODO: 5/16/2023 if requroes do if location not recived
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (SecurityException unlikely) {
            // TODO: 5/16/2023 ask permission or stop ride
        }
    }

    private void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotificationPermission")
    public void onNewLocation(Location location) {
        boolean isMock = false;
        isMock = location.isFromMockProvider();
        if (isMock) {
            new DbHelper(LocationUpdatesService.this).updateTripEnd();
            removeLocationUpdates();
            new DbHelper(this).updateRemark("Tried fake location", trip_id);

            if (!serviceIsRunningInForeground(LocationUpdatesService.this)) {
                tripEndBroadcast();
            }

            stopSelf();
            return;
        }
        try {
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                return;
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {

        }

        mLocation = location;

        if (data.size() != 0) {

            distance = distance + (distanceBetween(new LatLng(data.get(data.size() - 1).getLatitude(), data.get(data.size() - 1).getLongitude()), new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))) / 1000;

        }
        insertData(new DbHelper(this), location);

        data.add(location);

        // Notify anyone listening for broadcasts about the new location.
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_BROADCAST);
        intent.putExtra(EVENT, "location");
        intent.putExtra("distance", distance);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION, location);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);

        // Update notification content if running as a foreground service.
        if (serviceIsRunningInForeground(this)) {
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, getNotification());
        }
    }

    public boolean serviceIsRunningInForeground(Context context) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (getClass().getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                if (service.foreground) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private Notification getNotification() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationUpdatesService.class);


        // Extra to help us figure out if we arrived in onStartCommand via the notification or not.
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION, true);

        // The PendingIntent that leads to a call to onStartCommand() in this service.
        PendingIntent servicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // The PendingIntent to launch activity.
        PendingIntent activityPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, TripMapsActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .addAction(R.drawable.dl_thumb, "Open Trip", activityPendingIntent)
                .addAction(R.drawable.dl_back, "End Trip", servicePendingIntent)
                .setContentText("Trip started")
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setSound(null)
                .setSilent(true)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setTicker("setTicker")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

        // Set the Channel ID for Android O.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID); // Channel ID
        }

        return builder.build();
    }


    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public LocationUpdatesService getService() {
            return LocationUpdatesService.this;
        }
    }

 

    private void startTimer() {
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                count += 1;
                if (count > 16 * 60 * 60) {
                    new DbHelper(LocationUpdatesService.this).updateTripEnd();
                    removeLocationUpdates();
                    stopSelf();
                    if (!serviceIsRunningInForeground(LocationUpdatesService.this)) {
                        tripEndBroadcast();
                    }
                }
//                if (!serviceIsRunningInForeground(LocationUpdatesService.this)) {
//                    updateTimer(count);
//                }else {
//                    Log.d(TAG, "run: "+count);
//                }
                updateTimer(count);

            }
        }, 0, 1000);
    }

    private void stopTimer() {
        if (timer != null) {
            count = 0;
            distance = 0;
            data.clear();
            timer.cancel();
            timer.purge();
            timer = null;
        }
    }
}
```

I created this service for getting location in background and foreground . issue i am facing is when i reboot my phone and internet is not available my map doesnot load and it didnot give me my location update even if gps is on`

Comment: `created this service` Please add the line where you extend Service. Also show how and where you start your service. And tell Android version of used device.

Comment: My service is working perfectly this is only case when no cache of app and io start the app with internet off
` @Override
            public void onLocationAvailability(@NonNull LocationAvailability locationAvailability) {

                super.onLocationAvailability(locationAvailability);
                Log.d(TAG, "onLocationAvailability: "+locationAvailability.isLocationAvailable());
                enableLocation(locationAvailability.isLocationAvailable()); }`

i am getting false here

Comment: Using android 12

Comment: Please post your code in your post. Not unreadable in comments.